# find string that match specific regex then exclude from that list anything that match one ore more conditions

Tags: regex, file, grep

i'm using astrogrep to search email

to make it very tolerant i'm using this regex: `[a-z0-9_.-]+@[a-z0-9_.-]+`

but I have to ignore some email from that search

if i find ABCD or YXZ at the begining of the email, like `ABCDsomething@something.com` and `YXZ something@something.com` I have to exclude it from the result

I have tried a fews things like;

```
(?!abcd)|([a-z0-9_.-]+)@[a-z0-9_.-]+
^(?!abcd+)|([a-z0-9_.-]+)@[a-z0-9_.-]+
(?!abcd)([a-z0-9_.-]+)@[a-z0-9_.-]+
(?!abcd+)([a-z0-9_.-]+)@[a-z0-9_.-]+
```

etc...

this seem easy when i did my search on google but it seem i cannot find a way  to make it work

**edit**

create 3 text file in a folder
first file contain 3 lines:

> abcdsomething@something.com
>   xyzsomething@something.com
>   something@something.com

second file 1 line

> something@something.com

third file 3 lines

> email1="abcdsomething@something.com"
>   email2="xyzsomething@something.com"
>   email3="something@something.com"

with astrogrep search that folder, case NOT sensitive

expected result 1 email found in each file

with `[a-z0-9_.-]+@[a-z0-9_.-]+` i get all email properly but i just want to ignore the one that start with abcd / xyz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seem that the answer was this `\b(?!abcd|xyz)[a-z0-9_.-]+@[a-z0-9_.-]+`

Answer (score 0):

You can use negative lookahead like this:

```
(?!\b(abcd|xyz))[a-z0-9_.-]+@[a-z0-9_.-]+\b
```

This will fail the match if `abcd` or `xyz` is found at the start of input.

Comment: what this one does is; if it find abcdsomething@something.com in a file that contain a "valid email" like something@something.com, it it will work but if the file contain only valid email, it wont show that file

Comment: Can you show a small sample of file content in question?

Comment: question is updated, i will have to leave in about 15 minutes so i might only check any new answer tomorrow

Comment: hello, I just tried the new proposed regex and I'm not getting the expected result. what that one does is excluding the first letter of the email like this a`bcdsomething@something.com` instead of excluding the full email

Comment: But if the negative match is in the middle the regex will fail, like mattxyzsmith@mail.com? Maybe `^(?!abcd|xyz)[a-z0-9_.-]+@[a-z0-9_.-]+$` ?